# Why am I getting undefined method page for MongoID::Criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

Took over this project and updating to Rail 4.2.11. I haven't changed anything. We are using Kaminari. I am guessing Mongo is bringing back something now that it wasn't before? Or is Kaminari the issue?

I get the following error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `page' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x0070f088>):
```

on this line of code

```
@calls = MyRequest.desc(:timestamp_requested).page(params[:page])
```

FULL CODE:

```
def calls_admin
ensure_root
@sort = params[:s] || 'requested'
@direction = params[:d] || 'desc'
if @direction == 'desc'
  case @sort
  when 'status'
    @calls = MyRequest.desc(:status, :timestamp_requested).page(params[:page])
  when 'requested'
    @calls = MyRequest.desc(:timestamp_requested).page(params[:page])
  when 'yo'
    @calls = MyRequest.desc(:name, :timestamp_requested).page(params[:page])
  when 'length'
    @calls = MyRequest.desc(:calculated_mileage).page(params[:page])
  when 'time'
    @calls = MyRequest.desc(:time_in_seconds).page(params[:page])
  when 'billing'
    @calls = MyRequest.page(params[:page])
  end
```

end

Comment: Has `'kaminari-mongoid'` been added to the Gemfile?

Comment: Adding the GEM appears to work.